# Multiple Variables After controller In URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how to handle my routes and controller.

After a user registers on my site they receive an email with a link to the activate controller which asks for their password to confirm the account. However I'm trying to add an if statement to my controller so that it verifies that there are two parameters at the end of activate in the url and if there isn't then it will show my error page. Also it needs to verify that the first parameter is numeric.

For some reason I have something set up in correctly and not sure what.

Here's what I used for the route

```
$route['activate/:num/:any'] = "activate";
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Activate extends CI_Controller 
{ 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('kow_auth');            
}   

public function index()
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '<script src="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/assets/js/activatevalidate.js"></script>';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    if (is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3)) OR $this->uri->segment(4) == '')
    {
        $bodyContent = "error_page";
    }
    else
    {
        $bodyContent = "activate_form";//which view file
    }

    $bodyType = "full";//type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view('usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

function activate_submit()
{        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|alpha_numeric');

    $user_id            = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $registration_key   = $this->uri->segment(4);

    if (($registration_key == '') OR ($user_id == ''))
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'URL was not complete!')); 
    }
    else
    {
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) 
        {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!'));    
        }
        else
        {                           
            if ($this->kow_auth->activate_user($user_id, $registration_key, $this->input->post('password'))) 
            {
                echo json_encode(array('sucess' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Your account has been successfully activated!'));
            } 
            else 
            {                                                           
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'The activation code you entered is incorrect or expired!'));
            }
        }
    }


}

}

/* End of file activate.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/activate.php */
```

Error Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Error extends CI_Controller 
{ 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();           
}   

public function index()
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    $bodyContent = "error_page";//which view file

    $bodyType = "full";//type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view('usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

}

/* End of file error.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/error.php */
```

Any additional ideas?

**EDIT**
Even with the two answers below I'm still getting the same error messages.

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/activate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to agree with My_Mark, his answer is spot on based on what you initially asked for. So we are going to base this his initial answer.. Your problem is with the your if-else.

You will need

```
public function index($param1, $param2)
```

However I would change it to look more like

```
public function index($param1 = NULL, $param2 = NULL)
```

Also note this is for the index function of your controller if you have your controller set up where you have multiple views running out of it based on the function, such as your activate function for example. Then you will need to replace "index(" with "activate(".
Secondly from the looks of what your saying is if someone lands on the controller you want it to 404 or give some error. If the parameters aren't met. This is why I changed the above the way I did, this way your function isn't looking for parameters that aren't set and will likely error not being set. So we default them to NULL just in case.

So my solution would be to do something like..

```
$x = 0;
if(($param1 !== NULL)&&($param2 !== NULL))
{

    //params not null yay..
    if((isset($param1))&&((trim($param1) !== '')||(!empty($param1))))
    {
        if(!is_numeric($param1)
        {
          $x++;
        } 
    }
    if((isset($param2))&&((trim($param2) !== '')||(!empty($param2))))
    {
        if(/*whatever your constraint for $param2 (!preg_match()) or something*/)
        {
          $x++;
        } 
    }


    if($x !== 0)
    {
       $bodyContent = "error_page";
    }
    else
    {
       $bodyContent = "activate_form";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your routes to:

```
$route['activate/:num/:any'] = "activate/index/$1/$2";
```

This will allow you to pass in the two parameters into your index function of your activate controller like this:

```
public function index($param1, $param2)
```

You will then be able to do:

```
if (is_numeric($param1) OR $param2 == '')
{
    $bodyContent = "error_page";
}
else
{
    $bodyContent = "activate_form";
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Only one problem though when I go to this url it gives me a problem. http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/activate/ Which it should just show the 404 page. And if I do something like this as a test http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/activate/jdahkjf/271cce33ab11ced5fd10aeca41323a3c  then it shows up with some odd message.

Comment: I added the error controller which is the default 404 override controller but its the same template page code. Not sure why its giving me that error.